# MySQL - How to select data by date range one month?

Tags: mysql

I have a issue, how to get data by range date from one month

Example result

```
Name | start_date | endate
BEN  | 2016-02-13 | 2016-03-13
JONY | 2016-10-12 | 2016-11-12
JHON | 2016-11-04 | 2016-12-04
```

Comment: What's the table name? What's the table's schema? What have you writen so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try `DATE_ADD` in mysql

```
select name, start_date, DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL 1 month) as endate from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use these simple code to get the data from the table
by mentioning the right interval to get records added in last one month:

select * from my_table where  `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

hope this helps

Comment: thats not i mean, i mean i have field start_date and end_date. i will show date in date range one month